# How to use data entered in a text box in a separate class

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to take the data entered in 3 separate text boxes, pass that data through my dateinformation class and the print that out reformatted. I can't seem to figure out how to reference the data entered into the text boxes. I thought I had written it correctly but all that prints out is 0/0/0.

Here is the code from my form1

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnFormat_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFormat.Click
    Dim enteredDate As New DateInformation
    txtBoxResult.Text = ""
    txtBoxResult.AppendText(enteredDate.ToString)
End Sub
```

Here is the DateInformation class

```
Public Class DateInformation

Private month As Integer
Private day As Integer
Private year As Integer
Private frmone As New Form1

Public Sub New(ByVal initialmonth As Integer, ByVal initialday As Integer, ByVal initialyear As Integer)
    month = initialmonth
    day = initialday
    year = initialyear
End Sub

Sub New()
    ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
End Sub

Public Property sourceForm() As Form1
    Get
        Return frmone
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Form1)
        frmone = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property newmonth() As Integer
    Get
        Return month
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Try
            value = Convert.ToInt32(frmone.txtBoxMonth.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Value entered must be an integer")
        End Try
        value = month
    End Set
End Property


Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return month & "/" & day & "/" & year
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling the parameterless constructor for DateInformation (the one without parameters and that you have marked with the TODO comment). In this context the internal variable month, day and year are set to their initial default value that is 0 for integers. Of course the ToString override prints 0/0/0.

To fix your problem you need to call the DateInformation constructor that take 3 parameters

So supposing that you have 3 textbox named txtMonth, txtDay and txtYear the correct code is

```
Private Sub btnFormat_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFormat.Click
    Dim year as Integer
    Dim month as Integer
    Dim day as Integer

    if Not int32.TryParse(txtYear, year) Then
       MessageBox.Show("Enter a number for year")
       return
    End If 
    if Not int32.TryParse(txtMonth, month) Then
       MessageBox.Show("Enter a number for month")
       return
    End If 
    ' other checks for a valid month to follow here...

    if Not int32.TryParse(txtYear, day) Then
       MessageBox.Show("Enter a number for days")
       return
    End If 
    ' other checks for a valid days to follow here...

    Dim enteredDate As New DateInformation(month, day, year)
    txtBoxResult.Text = ""
    txtBoxResult.AppendText(enteredDate.ToString)
End Sub
```

Here I have made the checks for days, month and year external to your class because you need to check if the user input text (a string) is really an integer before calling your class constructor. You could add other checks for valid months and days.

Comment: Thanks for answering and that does solve the problem, but it looks like that makes the dateinformation class mostly useless. How could I fix the constructor? I have the random 'todo comment there just to make the error go away.

Comment: Just remove the empty constructor. You don't need it because this class has no meaning if there are no values. I don't know if this is all your code for this class. As is, there is little value here, because the standard DateTime class has many functionality built in and if you want to print a date as a formatted string you have many way to do it via [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) with standard or custom patterns